# Improper Encoding in Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, encoding, character-encoding

I started to get this weird issue with chrome (latest) where specific characters would be displayed as other characters.

Here is one example

[image]

so instead of `<` and `>` it displays `W` (with the thingy) and an upper 8

I can't even copy those characters since when I paste it displays properly, so I had to take a screenshot.

the HTML seems fine

```
<a data-remote="true" href="/prev" rel="prev">‹ Prev</a>
```

on safari it looks normal.

I've tried to disable extensions and tried in incognito, but it still the same.
In chrome language settings I have only one language (English (United States))

I also set chrome's encoding to auto-detect and UTF-8

I am using OS x (10.9)

Any ideas what can cause this?

Comment: Is this on all websites, or a specific set? Also, there seems to be a small "<" just before "Prev"

Comment: seems like all websites that have these characters. that little < is the character thats displaying the W with the thingy

Comment: Have you tried deleting the browser cache?

Comment: yes, it doesn't help

Comment: Can you verify that the bytes you are being served are exactly [e2 80 b9](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2039/index.htm)?